# $PQ$ is normal implies $P$ and $Q$ are also normal

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $P$ and $Q$ are two subgroups of a group $G$ of orders $p$ and $q$ respectively. Let order of the group is $2pq$, where both $p$ and $q$ are primes. Then are following things which is stated in my book, I can't understand.

$1)$ If either $P$ or $Q$ is normal then both $P$ and $Q$ are characteristic subgroups of $PQ$.
$2)$ If $PQ$ is normal in $G$ then obviously $P$ and $Q$ are normal in $G$.

I know that for the first case normality of either $P$ or $Q$ is required to exist the subgroup $PQ$ of $G$. But how can I say these?

Comment: Are p and q prime?

Comment: Yes, both p and q are primes.

Comment: It is possible for one of $P$ and $Q$ to be normal and the other not normal. For example there  are groups of order $42$ with a normal Sylow $7$-subgroup but with Sylow $3$-subgroups not normal. So 1) and 2) are both wrong.

Comment: @Derek Holt. Thank you. You are correct. This is wrong in general.